# Streaming compressed avi over network using directshow

Tags: c#, streaming, directshow.net, ffdshow

I'm quite new to Windows programming and I'm trying to setup a directshow graph to stream a webcam feed over a network so I can monitor the output on an ipad.

I've setup a graph in csharp using DirectShowLib and FFDShow that compresses the raw output from a capture device and writes it to an avi file.

Now I'm trying to work out how to broadcast the stream over the network.

The only sample code I can find for network streaming with directshow relates to the WM library which only seems to output Asf formatted streams.

How can I broadcast a stream in a format other than Asf using directshow? Can I configure the ASF Writer to output an avi/mpeg formated stream or do I need to write my own directshow filter?

Are there any examples of streaming avi over a network using directshow?

Thanks for reading,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up using VLC to create an MJPEG stream. I did try using VLS's HLS plugin but I found that iOS will only play one video at a time which was no good as I want to display several webcams. MJPEG gets round this.